# How to pass data(selected/clicked cell value) from TableViewController's Cell(Disclosure Detail) to the next ViewController loaded?

Tags: ios5, uitableview

I have a TableViewController with multiple cells(detail disclosure) each associated with unique data(eg. title/details). When I click one of the cells another ViewController gets loaded(via modal or push segue) and should display the data depending on which cell was clicked.

Simple Eg:

Each Cell of TableViewController are associaed with separate urls. When I click one of the cells(detail disclosure), the next ViewController that contains a WebView should open the web page corresponding to the url of the cell clicked.

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of accessing the data is to use the following inside the prepareForSegue method:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
```

This will give you the access to the selected row (cell) of the table so that you know which item your user has selected.

Then extract any data you need and pass it to the destination view controller using the prepareForSegue method as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set the identifier of each segue (in the storyboard, just click on the segue and set it in the Attributes Inspector).

Then, in your UITableViewController subclass, you need to override prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"] ) {
        UIViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.yourVariable = yourData;
    }
}
```

Comment: but how will I get yourData which is dependent on the cell clicked. The prepareForSeague is called before - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath so which cell was clciked and therefore the related data comes to us later :(!